# Laravel 4 - Eloquent result only shows (timestamps, incrementing, exists) when being assigned inside of another object

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

```
$city = City::with('station')->where('name',$town)->first();
$townID = 1;
$townComments = TownComment::where('town_id',$townID)->get();
$city->town_comments = $townComments;
```

When I do this, the result for the `town_comments` only shows `boolean` for the `timestamps`, `incrementing` and `exists`.

What am I doing wrong here?

here is how it looks like:

```
{
id: "1",
name: "tokyo",
similar_stations: {
    timestamps: false,
    incrementing: true,
    exists: true
}
}
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted this, if you are so professional then why don't you say your reason for downvoting -_-

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's being displayed like that because `$townComments` is an object automatically encoded to `JSON`, I forgot the reference where I read it but this is the solution.

```
$city->town_comments = $townComments->toArray();
```

Comment: It worked like a miracle! And yeah your explanation makes sense since what I have been doing is create a 
new ArrayObject(array(
   'comments'=>$townComments->comments,
));